# Deliver WildFly with default deployment

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final): 
I am searching for a possibility to trigger the deployment of my Java EE application (packed as EAR file), without starting the WildFly server or using the deployment-scanner. 
Is it possible to add the ear file to a configuration file, so that the server start the deployment of my application at the first time the server starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server has to be started to deploy anything. You can use [offline CLI](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/OfflineCLIWork) to deploy the content. This wouldn't actually process the deployment until the server has been restarted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That sounds like a good way to solve this problem. I will use a cli batch script to trigger the deployment. Therefore I had to start a "embed-server".